# Print out values in XMM registers

Tags: assembly, x86, avx

Hi I am having trouble printing out all my values in my xmm registers. I believe I am using SSE and AVX I am still very new to assembly

So the user inputs 4 numbers and I move them into YMM14 register using:

```
vmovupd ymm14, [rsp]
```

So now there is 4 numbers in ymm14. Next, I try to move them to xmm0 and xmm1 using

```
vextractf128 xmm1, ymm14, 1
vextractf128 xmm0, ymm14, 0
```

So now each holds two numbers. Now when I try to print them out using

```
mov rdi, devicePower                                        
mov qword rax, 4                                        
call printf
```

btw this is devicePower

```
devicePower db "Power (watts):    %.18lf    %.18lf    %.18lf    %.18lf", 10, 0
```

Only the low values get printed out. So if I input 1 2 3 4. Only 2 and 4 get printed out. I used debug and 1 & 2 are in the same register and 3 & 4 are also in the correct register together, but only 2 & 4 get printed out

Am i missing something because I can't get 1 & 3 to print. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You need to mention whether you're using Windows or Linux because the calling conventions vary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `printf` only treats `xmmN` registers as scalar, i.e. they only hold one value. Because your format string contains 4 different format specifiers, `printf` expects the values in 4 different registers (i.e. `xmm0`-`xmm3`). To print all 4 values, you will need to extract each field as a scalar to different registers.

So, the first step would be to split `ymm14` into two halves, `xmm0` and `xmm2` (*not* `xmm1`):

```
vextractf128 xmm0, ymm14, 0
vextractf128 xmm2, ymm14, 1
```

Next, split the two fields via `vshufpd`:

```
vshufpd xmm1, xmm0, xmm0, 1 ; the third operand doesn't matter
vshufpd xmm3, xmm2, xmm2, 1
```

Now, `xmm1` contains the higher-half of `xmm0`, and `xmm3` contains the higher half of `xmm2`.

Comment: slightly more efficient: `vunpckhpd xmm1, xmm0,xmm0` to grab the high half of XMM0.  Smaller code-size: no `imm8` control operand.  And for human readers, the shuffle operation is in the name instead of having to look at the number.  (Without AVX, `movhlps xmm1, xmm0` is even smaller, but if you haven't used `vzeroupper` yet then don't mix VEX with non-VEX.)